# How to use streams to get a running count?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a class

```
class Person {
    String name;
    ....
    Optional<Integer> children;
}
```

How do I use streams to get a total count of all children?

```
public int totalCount(final Set<Person> people) {
    int total = 0;
    for (Person person : people) {
        if (person.getChildren().isPresent()) {
            total += person.getChildren().get();
        }
    }
    return total; 
}
```

How can I do this with Java 8 streams?

```
public int totalCount(final Set<Person> people) {
    int total = 0;
    people.stream()
          .filter(p -> p.getChildren().isPresent())
          // ???
}
```

Comment: Any reason to use `Optional<Integer>` instead of `OptionalInt`? Or well, why are you using an optional at all? Is there a semantic difference between “zero children”, i.e. a present value of `0` or “no children”, i.e. an absent value?

Comment: I have a much larger and complicated class which is totally different. This was just an example I posted to see how this could be done. In a similar situation, yes just a basic 'int' would do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Collectors.summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-):

```
int count = people.stream()
      .filter(p -> p.getChilden().isPresent())
      .collect(Collectors.summingInt(p -> p.getChildren().get()));
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternative:

```
int sum = people.stream().mapToInt( p -> p.getChildren().orElse(0) ).sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variant would be to use `mapToInt` in order to obtain an `IntStream` and then call `sum()` on it:

```
int count = people.stream()
                  .filter(p -> p.getChildren().isPresent())
                  .mapToInt(p -> p.getChildren().get())
                  .sum();
```